# Elevator Traffic (Queueing Theory) Papers

Tags: optimization, reference-request, queuing-theory

I am about to start my final year thesis. The topic would be related to the queueing theory, specifically for the elevator traffic systems. I would need to do some literature review before going further into the topic and I would be very grateful if you could suggest some research papers about the topic.

I would need to do some programming to perform simulations for the queueing optimization later on. Can anyone please suggest which programming language/software I would be suitable for this research?

Answer (score 3):

I am not an expert in elevator traffic system simulation, but by googling you could find lots of related papers and literature. Some of them are as follows:

- [Modelling of Elevator Traffic Systems Using Queuing Theory](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273761657_Modelling_of_Elevator_Traffic_Systems_Using_Queuing_Theory)
- [The modeling and simulation of elevator group control systems for public service buildings](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1474667017358226)

Also, there are some useful simulation software like [Arena](https://www.rockwellautomation.com/en-us/products/software/arena-simulation.html), [Anylogic](https://www.anylogic.com/), etc. which either are frequently used in practice and cited in the papers. About the programming language python might be easy to use. If you are interested in software, one might be:

- [Passenger Flow Simulation to Optimize Elevator Traffic](https://www.anylogic.com/resources/articles/passenger-flow-simulation-to-optimize-elevator-traffic/)